# Dependency injection in PHP (slim, php-di)

Tags: php, slim, php-di, php-fig, psr-11

I have a Slim Php (slim4) application to which I added Monolog for logging purposes. I'm adding the logger to the application like this:

```
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
  LoggerInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
     $logger = new Logger('appname');
     ...
     return $logger
```

This works fine for injecting the logger in most of my classes, by just doing:

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container = null, LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    // I can use $logger here
```

**Now I'd also like to use the logger in the middleware like authentication.** I don't see how I can properly do this. 
I *can* get this working by adding the logger as a named entry in the container like this:

```
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
  "LoggerInterface" => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
```

and then passing it to the middleware as a constructor parameter by getting it back from the container:

```
$middlewares[] = new MyAuthentication(..., $container->get('LoggerInterface'));
```

But this:

- a) breaks the injection by classname for the other classes
- b) is
  [apparently](http://php-di.org/doc/best-practices.html) not a best practice

So what is the correct way to get this logger injected in the middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without adding the `LoggerInterface` as a named entry to the container, could you just inject the `LoggerInterface` class directly to your middleware via `$container->get()`? I.E. in a `routes.php` App function:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$app->add(new MiddleWare\MyAuthentication(..., $container->get(LoggerInterface::class)));
```

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I needed! (although it seems not to be best practice, it looks quite clean to me)

Answer (score 0):

In short, I do not think you are going to be able to auto-wire the dependencies for the middleware as they need to be constructed before being appended to the router.  You would need to explicitly inject the dependency as suggested by @Woodrow, although I would opt for method injection instead of constructor injection for the LoggerInterface as it would adhere to the LoggerAwareInterface.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How would the method injection work concretely? Does this mean passing the logger as parameter to each call to the class?

Comment: The [LoggerAwareInterface](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareInterface.php) provides a pretty good idea.  Just use a NullHandler or NoOpHandler for the classes logger member variable in the constructor.  Then the setter method just sets the objects member if desired.  You maybe able to use the PHP-DI factory to auto-wire up the constructor for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the dependency injection container (PHP-DI) resolve and inject all dependencies into your middleware:

```php
LoggerInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new Logger('name');
},
```

Then just register the middleware with the class name:

```php
$app->add(\MiddleWare\MyAuthentication::class);
```

(You should not inject the container itself into the middleware)

That's all.